# rails simple_form_for association select text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am using Rails 3.0, Ruby 1.9.2 and the Plataformatec simple_form gem.

The code below renders a select box with Consumer names. I want it to show a select box with  Consumer locations instead. How do I do that?

View code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @request do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :consumer, :collection => Consumer.all, :prompt => "Choose a location" %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Model code:

```
Consumer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :location
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would do this via label_method

```
<%= f.association :consumer, :collection => Consumer.all, :prompt => "Choose a location", :label_method=>:location %>
```